# Dart - For looping doesn't loop

Tags: dart

```
for(n = 0; n < length - 1; n++);
{   
    if(sbin[n] == '1'){
        ctr = ctr + 1;
        print(sbin[0]);
    }
}
return ('Bit counter - $ctr');
```

It only showed the 1st letter of sbin.

Comment: sorry. i forgot to delete that. I'm just checking if using sbin[n] would print it properly. But the if statement doesn't loop like the for loop.

Comment: Then I think you need to elaborate a bit about what you inputs, outputs, and expected outputs are.

Comment: I just need to count how many '1' were inputted. 
example 
input - 1011
ans - 3 
because there are 3 "1" on the string.

Comment: You have an extra semicolon at the end of line 1.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't noticed that!

Answer (score 1):

```
main() {
  print(someFunction());
}
  someFunction() {
  var length = 5;
  var sbin = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'];
  var ctr = 0;

  for(var n = 0; n < length - 1; n++) {   
      if(sbin[n] == '1'){
          ctr = ctr + 1;
          print(sbin[0]);
      }
  }
    return ('Bit counter - $ctr');
}
```

[**DartPad example**](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/ec9cb83fe92cfb0f57f8112985828bd5)